# Simple / elegant way to deconstruct a python bytearray?

Tags: python, parsing, arrays

I have a device connected to a CANbus, over which I'm receiving a series of bytearrays that I'm trying to process in python. I'm wondering what the best (simplest / most elegant) way to deconstruct the bytearray into it's constituent parts is. Currently, I'm just using a class with a number of variables corresponding to the various parts, and am loading each element manually in the constructor for the class. I was able to find [this](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/struct.html) online, but this only deals with "standard" packing (powers of 2), whereas here I have some fields that are odd sizes. Code below:

Struct (C++):

```
 struct struct_name {
  unsigned CloseLoopErrH:8;
  unsigned CloseLoopErrM:8;
  unsigned CloseLoopErrL:8;
  unsigned AppliedThrottle_h3:3;
  unsigned Fault_RevSoftLim:1;
  // ...
};
```

Python (using python-can to get the message over CAN):

```
class Parser(object):
    CloseLoopErrH = 0
    CloseLoopErrM = 0
    CloseLoopErrL = 0
    AppliedThrottle_h3 = 0
    Fault_RevSoftLim = 0
    Fault_ForSoftLim = 0
    # ...

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.CloseLoopErrH = msg.data[0]
        self.CloseLoopErrM = msg.data[1]
        self.CloseLoopErrL = msg.data[2]
        self.AppliedThrottle_h3 = (msg.data[3] & 0xE0) >> 5
        self.Fault_RevSoftLim = (msg.data[3] & 0x10) >> 4
        self.Fault_ForSoftLim = (msg.data[3] & 0x08) >> 3
        # ...

    def __str__(self):
        return """\
CloseLoopErrH: %d, CloseLoopErrM: %d, CloseLoopErrL: %d,
AppliedThrottle_h3: %d, Fault_RevSoftLim: %d, Fault_ForSoftLim: %d,
""" % (self.CloseLoopErrH, self.CloseLoopErrM, self.CloseLoopErrL,
       self.AppliedThrottle_h3, self.Fault_RevSoftLim, self.Fault_ForSoftLim)

def main():
    bus = can.interface.Bus()
    for msg in bus:
        print Parser(msg.data)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your variables as empty first and then call `unpack`

More documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

We can do characters:

```
>>> pack('5c', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o')
'hello'
>>> unpack('5c', 'hello')
('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o')
```

Or combinations:

```
>>> pack('ic', 0x12131415, '*')
'\x15\x14\x13\x12*'
>>> unpack('ic', '\x15\x14\x13\x12*')
(303240213, '*')
```

All the formats are in the documentation.

Comment: I'd like to do something like that, but unfortunately the format strings don't cover all of the possible options here - there are a few fields that are odd sizes, (3 bits, 5 bits, etc) which wouldn't be handled properly.

Comment: You can unpack as characters, and then get the specific byte code. I agree probably not the best solution